# How do I return a response from multiple get requests, inside an async.eachSeries loop, inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, get

I am attempting to return a new array, created by combining arrays from several get requests. The new array returns correctly within the `async.eachSeries` [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) function, however the parent function returns undefined.

My understanding is that the return within the parent function is running synchronously with the `async.eachSeries()` (before it can finish), which causes the parent function to return `undefined`.

```js
var array_strings = [ “someUrl”, “someUrl”, “someUrl” ]

function get_forEachUrlString(base_url, array_strings) {
    …
    var combinedArray = [];
    var mergedArray = [];
    …
    async.eachSeries(array_strings, function(item, done) {
        …
        $.get(bas_url+item, function(data) {
            …
            combinedArray.push(data)
            done(); // stopping the async looping
            mergedArray = [].concat.apply([], combinedArray); // Merging the array of combined arrays
        });
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("All requests are done");
        console.log(mergedArray); // logs correct array
        return mergedArray
    });
    console.log(mergedArray); // logs [] empty array
    return mergedArray // Hoping this would return the newly created mergedArray
}

get_forEachUrlString(“someBaseUrl”, array_strings) // Attempting to return mergedArray

// this function tries to call the mergedArray, but returns undefined
function initialRender() {
    …
    console.log(merged) // returns undefined
}
```

I have been searching for a way to get the parent function `get_forEachUrlString()` to return the value produced by the async.eachSeries function. I believe I will need to run a callback, but after trying several different combinations I’m still stumped.

How can I get the new array I’ve created, `mergedArray` to return from the function `get_forEachUrlString()`?

EDIT: I failed to mention that I am attempting to call the returned value from `get_forEachUrlString()` within `initialRender()`. See how I fixed this in my answer below.

Comment: there is no way to make `get_forEachUrlString` return the value - try using callbacks

Comment: @Jaromanda, how should I go about making that callback? They're still a little confusing for me, and I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I was able to get this working. I was attempting to place any number of callbacks, but what I really needed to do was place the `initialRender()` function within the `get_forEachUrlString()` function and pass the new `mergedArray` value to the initialRender() function.

So the proper setup looks like this.

```
function get_forEachUrlString(base_url, array_strings) {
    …
    async.eachSeries(array_strings, function(item, done) {
        …
    }, function(err) {
        …
        mergedArray = [].concat.apply([], combinedArray);
        initialRender(mergedArray);
    });
}

get_forEachUrlString(“someBaseUrl”, array_strings)
```

Then the `initialRender()` returns what it should.